# Gmail API messages.get not returning expected data

Tags: javascript, json, gmail-api

I'm trying to write an embedded gmail client and have been following through the API documentation on the developer site, but I am unable to get message data in my response. I am able to list labels no problem (using the code from the API docs) so I know it is authenticating ok. I am also able to get message IDs.

When I try to get actual message data, I am running into an issue where the returned Object does not have the data I expect. I check this by logging the messageRequest data to the console because message payload didn't exist when I was initially trying to access it.

```
function displayInbox() {
  var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
    'userId': 'me',
    'labelIds': 'INBOX',
    'maxResults': 10
  });

  request.execute(function(response) {
    $.each(response.messages, function() {
      var messageRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
        'userId': 'me',
        'id': this.id,
        'format': 'full'
      });
      console.log(JSON.stringify(messageRequest,null,4));
      messageRequest.execute(appendPre);
    });
  });
}
```

From developer console I get this output:

```
(index):473 {
    "Mq": 1,
    "Zq": {
        "QT": null,
        "k5": {
            "path": "/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/15f3a370bc482a7a",
            "method": "GET",
            "params": {
            "format": "full"
            },
            "headers": {},
            "root": "https://www.googleapis.com",
            "apiId": "gmail:v1"
        },
        "Ida": "auto",
        "Uja": false,
        "Tja": false
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are stringifying the request object. What you are looking at is not the response. Try `messageRequest.execute(function(response) { console.log(response); });` and see what you get.

Comment: That is the issue. Thank you very much that gave me the correct info. If you want to submit this as an answer I'll select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently doing `JSON.stringify` on the request object. What you are seeing in the console is not the response.

Try and wait for the `messageRequest` to finish asynchronously, and log the `response` in the callback instead:

```
var messageRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
  userId: 'me',
  id: this.id,
  format: 'full'
});
messageRequest.execute(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Thank you again for the answer. I have a follow up question. I added the code but have found that it prints out each message 15 times. Do you know why that may be?

Comment: @dtow1 Interesting. That's very hard to say without seeing more code, I'm afraid. Maybe open up a new question?